# Mask R-CNN Crack detection extending data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNN and python. I am currently working on a project that will detect a crack on concrete using Mask R-CNN. I found a repository on Github (https://github.com/rakehsaleem/Crack-Detection-TF-1.x.x) which pretty gave me everything I need. However, it is demanded that I should extend the provided dataset so that I can achieve greater accuracy for the detection. Now I want to use his dataset, then add up more images on it, and train my model with it. But I can't find any tutorial on how to do this. I can't open the provided JSON file on the VGG annotator. Please I don't want to start from scratch like annotating on thousands of images.

**Screenshot of files**
[image]

Is there a solution for this?
I guess I can use this .h5 file but I can't find a tutorial on how.

**Images and the JSON**
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to open the JSON file with python and looking at the content?  You can do this by following this tutorial: https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/  This should allow you to see the content and how the images are annotated. Then you just need to annotate your own images in the same way and add your data to the json file using python again.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for this. I will surely do it.